# Sharepoint 2010 - Custom WebPart Editor, Collapse Appearance Category

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've created a custom WebPart editor and I'm trying to figure out how to set the state of the Appearance Category to minimized.  By default the Appearance Category is expanded and the page automatically scrolls to this category.  More than likely there is a simple fix for this solution.  How can I set this category to minimize?